# Segmentation fault when passing a derived type as an optional argument

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following code produces a segmentation fault when compiled with gfortran:

```
module my_exceptions

  implicit none

  type::error_container
  end type error_container

contains

  subroutine throw(status)
    type(error_container), intent(out), optional::status
  end subroutine throw

  subroutine test_throw(status)
    class(error_container), intent(out), optional::status

    call throw(status)

  end subroutine test_throw

end module my_exceptions

program test
  use my_exceptions, ONLY: error_container, test_throw
  implicit none
  type(error_container)::status

  call test_throw()

end program test
```

It appears that gfortran is trying to do something with the `status` argument even though it is not present. The segmentation fault does not occur if the `status` is passed to test_throw(). Also, this code works as expected when compiled with ifort. Can anyone help me figure out what causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: Change the `class` keyword to `type` and your problem is resolved. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you mean `test_throw()` is a method of the class `error_container`, then you have to add it to the derived type as a type-bound procedure (in which case, it will be passed implicitly to the procedure (and you cannot make it optional).

Comment: @King thank you, that fixed it! Originally I was using an abstract type in the spot where the ```error_container``` type is used, hence the use of the ```class```. However, changes elsewhere in my codebase (not seen in the MWE I posted) resulted in a move to a concrete type.

Comment: What version of gfortran?

Comment: OK, fails with 7.5.0, 8.4.0, 9.3.0, 10.2.0, works with ifort 2021.1 Beta 20201112 and ifx 2021.1 Beta 20201113

Comment: (Fails also with 11.1.0.)

Comment: did you try having that optional as intent INOUT? (I have only ever used optional s as intent in.)

Comment: @Holmz, at your suggestion I tried intent(inout). It still crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Should have used `type(error_container)` instead of `class(error_container)` since error_container is a concrete type. Thanks to @King for pointing this out!

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong to use `class(error_container)`?

Comment: ```error_container``` is a concrete type, so ```class``` is not necessary here. Are you suggesting it should still work with class? If so it might be a compiler bug.

Comment: Yes. Just because the actual argument `status` is not polymorphic this does not mean that the dummy argument must be non-polymorphic.

Comment: @jhaiduce I've also tried with gfortran-10.2 and got the same segfault on Mac. Because this may be very likely a compiler issue, I would appreciate it if you consider posting it to [GCC bugzilla (bug reporting site)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&cf_known_to_fail_type=allwords&cf_known_to_work_type=allwords&component=fortran&product=gcc&query_format=advanced&resolution=---)

Comment: @roygvib, I just submitted a bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100743